# Python lxml html tostring

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml, confluence

I have the following Code and Output (without colon and text before it):

```
from lxml import html 
root = html.fromstring('<ac:link> <ri:attachment filename="test.pdf"/> </ac:link>')
html.tostring(root,encoding='unicode',method='xml')
```

> Output : `'<link> <attachment ri:filename="test.pdf'/> </link>`

However, I have expected some similar to this (keeping the original tag structure):

> Output : `'<ac:link> <ri:attachment ri:filename="test.pdf'/> </ac:link>`

Is there a way to produce the wanted output ? (I cant change the HTML structure as is).

Maybe somebody could also point to the relevant part in the source code.

Comment: This appears to be related to [tag:confluence]. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html#ConfluenceStorageFormat-Links. `<ac:link> <ri:attachment filename="test.pdf"/> </ac:link>` is not standard HTML and it's not well-formed XML either.

Comment: in `ac:link` the `ac` is a namespace reference. you may need to look into namespace or namespace awareness